# WPF Button Inner Border

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF development, I am creating a button style as per my designer provided it.
[image]

While creating button, I am facing an weird problem. I am not finding way Remove button Radius. I tried "Round Corner = false", but it is removing only Right side round corners. Moreover I am not finding way how to remove Inner silver border in button. I think this issue is caused because there is a default style applied to button, (chrome style in my case).

[image]

Is there any way to can I remove all round corners and Inner Border.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Can you post your Xaml style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
 and the
  `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">`
 part and find this line
 `<Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" ...`
and as you gussed this is why. To change, you should use your custom style.
this linke might help you too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163421.aspx